# Using Python Script to get equal name as given and compare to multiple shp file in folder and copy as output for tool?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

The following images will show my model. I used a piece of Python script and trying to get the output from it as a layer and use it for rest of the tool. However, I am getting error as displayed in one of the following image. could someone help me on solving this problem.

[image: Python Script Used in Model-Builder]
[image: Error Code After Running the model]

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
Match_FC=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Match_F=Match_FC[-13:-4]
#env.workspace =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
# Copy shapefiles to a folder 
for fc in fcList:
    for fc in fcList:
        print fc[-13:-4]
        if fc[-13:-4]==Match_F:
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('in_memory\fc', 'in_memory\output','')
            break
```

> ERROR 00229: Cannot open 
>   C:\User\Documents\ArcGis\Default.gdb\Rel_AA_001_Compari
>   Failed to execute (Make Feature Layer)

Comment: Please always include errors as text rather than pictures so that they can be searched for.  I suspect that you will have trouble attracting a potential answerer to this one because you are showing us your whole model and code instead of extracting a minimal test model and test code out.

Comment: I added my code and took out extra information. I believed the error can be shown as screenshot.

Comment: I and any other potential answerers of your questions all volunteer our time to help question askers, but our prime goal is to build high quality content for the GIS Stack Exchange, so that people do not need to ask for answers, they just find them instead.  To help us in our endeavours to help you and others we want to teach you as quickly as possible how to write high quality questions. There is a good summary of that philosophy in this Q&A http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4181/too-many-questions-on-hold-and-closed

Comment: OK, Thx for clear answer and helping others. I relay appreciate your help and others. I found this web site very helpful and valuable. Thx again for all your/others support.

Comment: Also may I ask what happened if you delete a question. I post a question similar to this one and I found this way might work and if this happen I will repost my question and will answer by referring to this way. Thx again for all your volunteer time and other supporters.

Comment: It is unwise to delete too many questions too soon after you join a Stack Exchange site because they feed into the formula that automatically imposes question bans.  It is far preferred that questions are improved by editing.  I note that you have not yet taken the [Tour] which leads into the [help/on-topic] where how Stack Exchange works is described in more detail.  It is very different, and I think much better, than any discussion forums and other Q&A sites that I have used.

Comment: I can see the error message in your picture, but we ask for error messages as text, so that searches by other people experiencing the same error can see it too.

Comment: Thx for helping me to post correct question. I added my error as text format. In future, I will post a short but complete question with detailed and all sample or part of code and error will be in text format for testing/evaluating.

Comment: May show me, how to answer my own question? I figured out the problem and tool is running great. Thx for all help and advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37118/discussion-between-koush-and-polygeo).

Comment: To answer your own question just type your answer into the answer box. Try to make it as clear as possible - and feel free to make your question clearer too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just add one more line to get parameter as text and then I created a script or Python tool. The parameters for this tool are: 2 inputs and 1 output.
I also added an arcpy. Deletemanagement before output to clean the output after each run. Also I took out the in_memory function from the make feature layer line, then added an extra variable and equaled it to the name/value from iterator and used it for entire script.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you included a working code snippet instead of describing how a non-working code snippet would need to be modified to make it work.